# javascript onclick only works after second click

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

Currently trying to add a simple on click function on a nav/menu.

Each item has children so it is a dropdown. On mobile, the full menu is revealed with the dropdowns as well. My task is to make a small toggle for mobile devices.

I wrote a small script that

1. prevents the default action
2. the sub-menu is revealed on click.

The website is on wordpress and the script has to be pure JS.

Here is the code, it works but only on the second click

```
document.getElementById("menu-item-69").addEventListener("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var x = document.getElementById("menu-item-69");
    x.onclick = function(){
        var y = document.getElementById("menu-item-69").querySelectorAll(".sub-menu");
        y[0].style.display = ((y[0].style.display!='block') ? 'block' : 'none')
    };


})
```

HTML

```
<li id="menu-item-69" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-60 current_page_item menu-item-has-children menu-item-69"><a href="#" aria-current="page">UNTERNEHMEN</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-316" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-316"><a href="/blog">AKTUELLES</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-265" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-265"><a href="#">KARRIERE</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-293" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-293"><a href="#">KOOPERATIONEN</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-298" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-298"><a href="#">LINKS</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: well why are you binding an onclick event inside of an onclick event? Why is that logic not just there? You click once to bind a different onclick function. So you click a second time and it fires that newly bound function.... So the way you coded it, it needs two clicks. Get rid of the extra onclick.

Answer (score 0):

**This line get the element ( HTML Tag with that ID ):**

```
document.getElementById("menu-item-69")
```

**With this line already assign the click event:**

```
document.getElementById("menu-item-69").addEventListener("click", function(event){
```

**This is stopping the first click:**

```
event.preventDefault();
```

**Then assign again an event listener click:**

```
var x = document.getElementById("menu-item-69");
```

**Second click assigned:**

```
     x.onclick = function(){
            var y = document.getElementById("menu-item-69").querySelectorAll(".sub-menu");
            y[0].style.display = ((y[0].style.display!='block') ? 'block' : 'none')
        };
})
```

***So the answer, is do the same but instantly :***

```
document.getElementById("menu-item-69").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var y = document.getElementById("menu-item-69").querySelectorAll(".sub-menu");
    y[0].style.display = ((y[0].style.display != 'block') ? 'block' : 'none')
    console.dir(y);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code says that when the user clicks first time assign that click even inside the code
it does not perform that function

```
function(){
        var y = document.getElementById("menu-item-69").querySelectorAll(".sub-menu");
        y[0].style.display = ((y[0].style.display!='block') ? 'block' : 'none')
    };
```

it just assigns it to the `x.onclick` so remove that assignment and perform put your code directly into. event listener
i.e.

```js
document.getElementById("menu-item-69").childNodes[0].addEventListener("click", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        //var y = document.getElementById("menu-item-69").querySelectorAll(".sub-menu");
           var y = document.getElementById("menu-item-69").querySelectorAll(".sub-menu");
        y[0].style.display = ((y[0].style.display!='block') ? 'block' : 'none')    
       
    })
```

```css
.sub-menu{
  display: none
}
```

```html
<li id="menu-item-69" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-60 current_page_item menu-item-has-children menu-item-69"><a href="#" aria-current="page">UNTERNEHMEN</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
     <li id="menu-item-316" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-316"><a href="/blog">AKTUELLES</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-265" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-265"><a href="#">KARRIERE</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-293" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-293"><a href="#">KOOPERATIONEN</a>
     <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li id="menu-item-298" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-298"><a href="#">LINKS</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it work great with the parent toggle but it also affects the children (list items in the dropdown) and they are not clickable, any idea how I can change that?

Comment: you need to post some more code i.e. html as well to let us understand where the actual problem resides

Comment: Added HTML in the main post

Comment: try this way, change the click event's target to `<a>`

Comment: I can't make direct changes to the HTML since it's in wordpress and the html is automatically generated